# Using foreign key to bilateral action

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I use foreign key for my tables:

**Table A**

```
-----------------------------------------
id    |  name   |  type   | date
-----------------------------------------
1     |test.jpg |image/jpg| 2015-01-15
2     |test2.jpg|image/jpg| 2015-01-15
3     |test3.jpg|image/jpg| 2015-01-15
```

and **Table B**

```
-----------------------------------------
id    |  title  | file_id | date
-----------------------------------------
1     |News 1   |1        | 2015-01-15
2     |News 2   |2        | 2015-01-15
3     |News 3   |3        | 2015-01-15
```

this is my foreign key for **Table B**  :

```
CONSTRAINT `news_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`file_id`) REFERENCES `Table A` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Now everything is ok, I want to know is there any way to say if I delete one record from `Table B` the `file_id` record delete from `Table A` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I understand that "TableA.id" is the parent of "TableB.file_id".

In that case you can only delete something from "TableA.id" is there are no children. Also the value from "TableB.file_id" must exist in "TableA.id".

What you could do is put a trigger on "TableB" that activates when a delete has been done. Then you could look if the value "TableB.file_id" from the line you deleted is still being used in "TableB.file_id". If that is not the case, then delete you can delete it from "TableA".

Here is a link about triggers: [Triggers](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/)

I think it you need to use an "after delete trigger". 
Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trName 
AFTER DELETE ON TableB

BEGIN 
    <look if any values from "TableA.id" are not used anymore in "TableB.file_id">
    <if that is the case, do a DELETE on that "TableA.id" line>
END;
/
```